# Switched Wifi Driver but still on old

Tags: drivers

After trying out ubuntu on a virtual machine and having success I chose to switch over to it full time. I have run into one major issue with my wifi however.

On my old Windows 10 OS I had to buy a new USB adapter because the old one was faulty. This worked fine after I installed the driver that was only applicable to windows 10.

Now that I am on Ubuntu full time however, my computer is still using the old wifi card and driver instead of the new one. I found from a previous post that I needed to use a NdisWrapper which I was able to do succesfully. I followed the instructions which follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210  
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
```

When I try to get online using my regular wifi now (I have been using a portable hotspot via USB on my iphone) it seems to be still using the old card. **I guess my main question here is how do I switch over to this new driver and adapter so I can actually use my wifi?**

`lsusb` provides the following:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 13d3:3414 IMC Networks   
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9053 NetGear, Inc.   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1532:0504 Razer USA, Ltd   
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c335 Logitech, Inc.   
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 046d:c07d Logitech, Inc.   
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 008 Device 009: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6  
Bus 008 Device 006: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp.   
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B) (rev 02)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port D)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port E)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port G)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 OEM]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
06:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

.

```
Output of dmesg | tail: 
[   26.547795] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   26.547802] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   26.547806] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   76.047379] usb 9-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   77.732113] usb 9-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   77.754857] usb 9-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0846, idProduct=9053
[   77.754860] usb 9-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   77.754862] usb 9-1: Product: A6210
[   77.754863] usb 9-1: Manufacturer: NETGEAR
[   77.754865] usb 9-1: SerialNumber: 100
```

Comment: Can you also post the output of `lspci`?

Comment: @QwertyChouskie http://pastebin.com/mcBDs6kQ

Comment: What is the model of the adapter?

Comment: Also, what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Exact Purchase Information: NETGEAR - AC1200 Wireless-AC High-Gain Wi-Fi USB 3.0 Adapter - Black. Model Number:  A6210-10000S. SKU: 8860004

Comment: @QwertyChouskie Running newest version of desktop Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: When clicking the WiFi button in the tray, do you see multiple adapters listed?: http://i.imgur.com/zWNFCiP.png

Comment: @QwertyChouskie When I click the wifi button with just my adapter plugged no adapters are listed. When I plug in my Iphone via USB I see: Ethernet Network (Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller).

Comment: Unplug and re plug in the WiFi adapter, then post the output of `dmesg | tail`.

Comment: Also, did you reboot after installing the driver?

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, try plugging it into a USB 2 port.

Comment: @QwertyChouskie I did reboot when downloading driver. I added the dmesg | tail output to original post at the bottom

Comment: @QwertyChouskie Added new information: I have disconnected my iphone and turned off the hotspot so I am now connected to my home wifi. However my home wifi is usually at about 200mb down and its currently at .14mb down so something is still off. No adapters are listed on the top right menu bar